# Adding multiple subtitles in generic template

Tags: chatbot, facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot, messenger, facebook-chatbot

The generic template docs of the messenger api has an image that shows 3 lines of subtitles. I'm unable to figure out how to get this done.
[Generic Tepmlate Image Attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bOqpi.png)

Answer (score 1):

Solved it. The text is UTF-8. Using /n creates a new line